# Kendo Grid, how to make column filterable by dropdown menu?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to ask, how to change in Kendo Grid component column filterable input (see image below) into dropdown menu with two given values (CZ and EN)?

[image]

Many thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I tried to do by this way, but with no effect:

```
 {
                field :"language",
                title : $translate.instant('LANG'),
                type: "string",
                width:220,
                filterable: {
                  ui: function (element) {
                    element.kendoDropDownList({
                      dataSource: ['CZ','EN'],
                      optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
                    });
                  }
                }
            },
```

Comment: you can have a look at [this example](http://refork.com/x4dc) too. look at _category_ field

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial, it should give you information how to do it
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization

---

Sorry, Is this that you are trying to achieve ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working, check my updated question

Comment: Thats weird, it worked on kendo dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/eXUzu . Check city filter

Comment: Oh, I see, but i wanted it displayed instead of the vissible text input.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by applying below code

```
{        
    field: "language",
    title: "Language",
    width: 150,
    filterable: {                       
        multi: true,
        dataSource: [
            { language: "CN" },
            { language: "EN" }
        ]            
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you